# Word to indicate a project or endeavor whose benefits are insubstantial (particularly in relation to it's costs)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Many programming languages are routinely created with promises of a new sort of paradigm that will eliminate inefficiency from the process of creating software. Like most of us who set out to change the world, they frequently find it difficult to manage their own and their solutions frequently create larger problems.

What is a good word or phrase that describes these sort of "Pyrrhic quagmires" that are "not worth the effort"?

Comment: That's called "*a bad investment*"

Comment: @Jim Definitely a good phrase that fits the bill, but are there any others that do provide the same tone of negativity?

Comment: *Do*? or *Don't*?

Comment: My apologies, you are absolutely right -- *don't*

Comment: Do you mean something like *boondoggle*?

Comment: Boondoggle is definitely closer, but I'm looking for something closer to "reinventing the wheel" without such a strong implication that everything could have been done with other tools. Imagine paying 10,000 for a new computer whose only new feature is that it displays your email in the right hand corner -- it's useful, sure, but it's completely out of proportion to it's cost.

Comment: That might be called *extravagant*

Comment: "A complete waste of time and resources"? Maybe throw an expletive in there? "All for naught"? "All smoke, no fire"/"All bark, no bite"? "All that glitters is not gold"?

Comment: If you're open to idioms, then I'd say that the Project "backfired"  and consequently, those involved in the Project "got their fingers burnt". If this works for you, I'll convert to an answer.

Comment: Maybe 'ineffectual'.

Comment: Disappointing...

Comment: Wasted, worthless or futile efforts or exertion ?

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps idiomatically a ***white elephant***!

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/white%20elephant):

> **white elephant**
>   *noun*
>
> : something that requires a lot of care and money and that gives
>   little profit or enjoyment

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_elephant):

> A ***white elephant*** is a possession which its owner cannot dispose
>   of and **whose cost, particularly that of maintenance, is out of
>   proportion to its usefulness**. The term derives from the story that
>   the kings of Siam, now Thailand, were accustomed to make a present of
>   one of these animals to courtiers who had rendered themselves
>   obnoxious, in order to ruin the recipient by the cost of its
>   maintenance. 
>   **In modern usage, it is an object, scheme, business venture, facility, etc., considered without use or value**.

Answer (score 1):

A ***black hole***.

Definition of [**black hole**](http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=black-hole) - Financial Times:

> A business activity or product on which large amounts of money are
>   spent, but that does not produce any income or other useful result.

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/black%20hole):

> Full Definition of **black hole**
>
> 2 a :  something that consumes a resource continually : a financial
>   **black hole**